# Query is Related to Mysql Records and fetch few of them

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have 10 Records in my database and I want 5 records from it.

Like `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` and I want records from `3,4,5,6,7,8`

Records are dynamic and can change very frequently.

```
 Select * 
 From file 
 Where file_status = 1 
 Order By file_date DESC 
 limit 5
```

This Won't work, just because this will fetch only last five records..

Comment: You should use the MySQL function for `OFFSET 2`

Comment: Can you post table structure and some sample data here?

Comment: `Records are dynamic and can change very frequently` what does that mean? What is the logic behind what do you want? Do you ALWAYS want the records from 3, ..., 8 or this can change? If yes, what can change and what do you want so? With no logic we can't help and guess what you want !

Comment: Where you want say records 3,4,5,6,7,8 are they id numbers (an id field)?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from file where file_status = 1 order by file_date DESC limit 2,6
```

will get data as your examp

Comment: What if I am unaware about my last records for 'ID', because my all data is dynamic and can change frequently.

Comment: so exactly your requirement is ? need to make a logic for this issue